# Need to print mysql data in to json in a format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, pdo

I am trying to get mysql data in to json using php and later access it in url. I am getting data in json but i need in a format. Below is my php code to get json.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include('dbhconfig.inc.php');

$response = array();

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM venderlist");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 { 
     $response['results'] = $rows; 
    }
echo json_encode($response);
```

And my json data showing as bellow

```
{"results":[{"id":"1","vendname":"Genie Events","address":"15, Lower Ground Floor, Lajpat Nagar, Delhi - 110024, Near National Park ","contact":"(91)-11-33437065","contact_o":"(91)-11-40666522","est":"2010","website":"www.genieevents.com","email":"","zip":"110024","latitude":"1.28525","longitude":"103.775464","latlon":"1.28525,103.775464","type":"organisers"},
```

First of all its not showing in proper structure. And presently latlon is showing like `"latlon":"1.28525,103.775464"` but i want result should be `"latlon":[1.28525,103.775464]`

How to add `[]` to my json variable name latlon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If course, you'll need to break down that part of the data first since its a string. You'll need to set them up as an array unit with both float values inside.

After fetching them all, you'll need to make a little bit of operations.

You can use `explode` on that string first with that `,`. So that becomes an array `[]`. But it doesn't end there, the exploded elements are still strings, so you can map out all elements with `floatval` with the use of `arrray_map`.

So all in all, it would look just like this:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as &$r) { // with reference
    // explode with comma, map with floatval
    $r['latlon'] = array_map('floatval', explode(',', $r['latlon']));
}
echo json_encode(array('results' => $rows)); // json encode
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I think you could do it in one line like this: `echo json_encode(array('results' => array_map(function($row){ return array_map('floatval', explode(',' $row['latlon'])); }, $rows)));`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy haha, the one liner array functions incantation, of course, it always has one

Comment: your operation is success. Thank you. i got what i want.

Comment: @AseshaGeorge just use `LIMIT OFFSET` in mysql

Comment: LIMIT OFFSET is ok but please see the bottom of the page its showing all record count and no.of pages and records per page. see the link  sbadb.herokuapp.com/v1/bizs . see under meta